# Preon enum interpretation and mapping

Tags: java, dictionary, enums, preon

According to http://www.scribd.com/doc/8128172/Preon-Introduction ,
Preon can be used to decode bits into an enum representation as such:

`// Reads a bit from the buffer, and interprets it as an enum value,

    // interpreting the number as its ordinal value.

    @BoundNumber(size="2")

    Type type;`

Now, my question is: if you have an enum such as:

    `public static enum TestEnum {

        VALUE_A, VALUE_B

    }`

Does 00 always map to VALUE_A, and 01 always to VALUE_B because they are written in that (ascending?) order?
Can I count on this always being the case?
In what ways are enums valued in Java and how does Preon resolve this situation?

Comment: Please not that the @BoundEnumOption(value=X) is required on the describing class, and that byte-order needs to be considered within the byte itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they do. The javadoc of the synthetic method `values()` states it. See [JLS 8.9.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2).

> Returns an array containing the constants of this enum type, in the order they're declared.  This method may be used to iterate over the constants as follows:

and the javadoc for [Enum.ordinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) states

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero).

So if you do

```
TestEnum.values[0]
```

you will always get

```
TestEnum.VALUE_A
```

in your case.

Comment: So the ordinal will always start at 0 and increase such that:
VALUE_0 "=0", 
VALUE_1 ="1", ...,
VALUE_N ="N"

There is no exception to this rule?

Answer (score 1):

The ordinal always maps to the declared order of the enums. However, I would be wary of ever using the ordinal like that. If another developer changes the ordering of the enum declarations, your program will break in very subtle ways. I believe Josh Bloch mentions this in Effective Java.